# Send value with Firestore query

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Is there any way to send custom value with every or single Firestore query like this:

```
this.fireStore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
```

I need to send a value to access it on Firebase rules like

```
allow=true
```

For example :

```
this.fireStore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).params({allow:true, healthy:good}).valueChanges()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the variables you are trying to send?

Comment: @JackWoodward I have added an example

Comment: Thanks. No thats not possible. Security rules for document gets can only look at its own values in the document and the request object. You would want to look at using the values in the document you are getting or you could look at custom auth claims if they are user properties - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#properties

Comment: @JackWoodward thanks

Comment: @JackWoodward That sounds like an answer. :-)

Comment: Shame you cant upgrade a comment @Frank van Puffelen. Added as an answer

Comment: What makes these values different from query parameters, which are [partially available in rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query)?

Answer (score 1):

No thats not possible. Security rules for document gets can only look at its own values in the document and the [request object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#properties). You would want to look at using the values in the document you are getting, security rule looking like this for example

```
allow read: resource.data.public == true
```

or

You could look at [custom auth claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) if they are user properties e.g. if admin etc. and its security rule looking something like this for example

```
allow read: request.auth.token.admin === true
```